# Salvar imagem em diretório sem SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de controle de estoque e nessa aplicação existe uma tela de cadastro de produtos:

[image: Tela de cadastro de produtos]

As imagens dos produtos estão sendo salvas no banco de dados do MySQL. Recebi umas dicas e dentre elas estava a de que não é recomendável salvar imagens no banco de dados, até porque o campo de busca de produtos na tela de consulta estava muito lento, pois a imagem é convertida em byte da seguinte forma:

```
public void CarregaImagem(String imgCaminho)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgCaminho))
                return;
            //fornece propriedadese métodos de instância para criar, copiar,
            //excluir, mover, e abrir arquivos, e ajuda na criação de objetos FileStream
            FileInfo arqImagem = new FileInfo(imgCaminho);
            //Expõe um Stream ao redor de um arquivo de suporte
            //síncrono e assíncrono operações de leitura e gravar.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgCaminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            //aloca memória para o vetor
            this.ProFoto = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(arqImagem.Length)];
            //Lê um bloco de bytes do fluxo e grava osdados em um buffer fornecido.
            int iBytesRead = fs.Read(this.ProFoto, 0, Convert.ToInt32(arqImagem.Length));
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

E salva no banco da seguinte forma:

```
public void Incluir(ModeloProduto obj)
    {    
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao.ObjetoConexao;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Produto (pro_foto) " +
        "values (@foto); select @@IDENTITY;";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@foto", MySqlDbType.LongBlob);
        if (obj.ProFoto == null)
        {
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro_foto", DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters["@foto"].Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro_foto", obj.pro_foto);
            cmd.Parameters["@foto"].Value = obj.ProFoto;
        }
    }
```

Na tela de consulta, a imagem é passada do banco de dados para o PictureBox quando o usuário digita o nome ou código de barras do produto. Porém gostaria de mudar isso. Ao invés de salvar a imagem no banco de dados, quando o usuário cadastrar um produto e clicar para salvar, a imagem ser automaticamente passada do PictureBox da tela de cadastro, para um diretório dentro da pasta do programa e quando fizer uma pesquisa na tela de consulta, a imagem ser recuperada do diretório para o PictureBox. A imagem também ser salva com o número do código do produto na hora do cadastro.

Botão "Adicionar foto" da tela de cadastro:

```
private void btLoFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
            od.ShowDialog();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(od.FileName))
            {
                this.foto = od.FileName;
                pbFoto.Load(this.foto);
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Algum erro ocorreu! Você pode estar tentando enviar outros tipos de arquivos \n" 
                + "que não são imagens, selecione arquivos do tipo .png, .jpg, .bitmap,  por exemplo.", "Erro");
        }
    }
```

Tela de consulta de produtos:

[image: Tela de consulta de produtos]

Código para recuperar a imagem do banco:

```
try
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(modelo.ProFoto);
                    pbFoto.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    this.foto = "Foto Original";
                }
                catch { }
```

Classe ModeloProduto:

```
public ModeloProduto(String pro_foto)
       {
           this.CarregaImagem(pro_foto);
       }
public ModeloProduto(byte[] pro_foto)
       {
           this.ProFoto = pro_foto;
       }
private byte[] _pro_foto;
        public byte[] ProFoto
        {
            get { return this._pro_foto; }
            set { this._pro_foto = value; }
        }

public void CarregaImagem(String imgCaminho)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgCaminho))
                    return;
                //fornece propriedadese métodos de instância para criar, copiar,
                //excluir, mover, e abrir arquivos, e ajuda na criação de objetos FileStream
                FileInfo arqImagem = new FileInfo(imgCaminho);
                //Expõe um Stream ao redor de um arquivo de suporte
                //síncrono e assíncrono operações de leitura e gravar.
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgCaminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                //aloca memória para o vetor
                this.ProFoto = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(arqImagem.Length)];
                //Lê um bloco de bytes do fluxo e grava osdados em um buffer fornecido.
                int iBytesRead = fs.Read(this.ProFoto, 0, Convert.ToInt32(arqImagem.Length));
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você já tem a imagem num picturebox e quer salvá-la localmente, certo? Mas de vai vir essa imagem do picturebox? Do banco de dados? Vai precisar validar se a imagem veio do banco ou não?

Comment: A parte do banco de dados eu quero excluir, só mostrei como se dá o processo. O usuário no caso, faz o carregamento da imagem de algum lugar do computador para o PictureBox, e queria que essa imagem fosse salva numa pasta pré-definida no computador, e que fosse carregada para o picturebox quando o usuário fizesse uma pesquisa de produto.

Comment: Perfeito, entendi agora. Eu já monto um exemplo pra você.

Comment: @jbueno O exemplo?

Comment: Jovem, desculpe a demora. Tá lá seu exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde que o PictureBox contenha uma imagem válida, você pode recuperá-la usando a propriedade `Image` do componente e salvá-la usando o método [`Image.Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void SalvarImagem()
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save("D:\\teste.jpg", pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
}
```

Perceba que o segundo parâmetro do método `Save` pede um [`ImageFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx) (o tipo da imagem - JPG, PNG, etc.), como essa informação já existe na imagem é possível recuperá-la sem muito esforço usando a propriedade `RawFormat`.

Sim, é só isso! Claro que você precisará fazer alguma coisa pra para colocar a extensão no nome do arquivo, mas isso é só um detalhe pequeno.

---

Para encontrar determinado arquivo em um diretório específico, é necessário usar [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx). Criei um pequeno exemplo pra você, obviamente tem que adaptar para suas necessidades, mas a base é essa.

```
public Image buscarImagemProduto(string pastaPadrao, string nomeUnicoArquivo)
{
    string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(pastaPadrao, nomeUnicoArquivo);

    if(arquivos.Length > 1)
        MaisDeUmArquivoEncontrado();
    else if (arquivos.Length == 0)
        NenhumArquivoEncontrado();
    else
        return Image.FromFile(arquivo[0]);

    return null; // Qtd de arquivos é diferente de zero - adapte para suas necessidades
}
```

Comment: Para recuperar a imagem quando o usuário digita o nome do produto ficaria como? (A imagem está sendo salva com o nome do produto fornecido no cadastro de produtos)

Comment: Você só quer saber como recuperar uma imagem pelo nome, certo? Pelo seu comentário parece que você quer que eu crie toda a regra pra você...

Comment: Bom cara, não é isso, só quero saber como recuperar também, isso está escrito ali em cima, preciso saber que código usar..

Comment: Tranquilo, jovem. Eu só queria saber se eu tinha entendido certo o que você quis dizer. Não disse que é isso que você quer... =)

Comment: Desculpe a má interpretação também! :D Aguardo sua tão preciosa ajuda!!

Comment: @MarlonLeandro Adaptei a resposta. Mal a demora, tô um pouco corrido nos últimos dias.

Answer (score 0):

Se é uma aplicação windows forms, a imagem já existe no pc do usuário, então pra gravar você pode simplesmente copiar o arquivo para sua pasta, já renomeando, usando a função Copy da classe File (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.100).aspx).

Pra ler, você pode usar a função ReadAllBytes da mesma classe (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.100).aspx) ao invés de carregar do banco de dados.

Comment: Mas Quando o usuário clica em "Adicionar foto" Abre um FileDialog e a imagem aparece no PictureBox da tela de cadastro, então teria que copiar do PictureBox para uma pasta, esse primeiro código, tem que informar o source, no entanto não se aplica no meu caso

Comment: Quando você informa o caminho da imagem que o usuário selecionou no FileDialog no método Load da PictureBox, esse caminho fica disponível na propriedade ImageLocation da PictureBox. Quando você for salvar, basta usar como source essa propriedade.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo, por gentileza?